# Start Glassfish in Netbeans 10 with JDK11

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to configure everything to develop a web application, but I am not expert about that and I am having problems to start Glassfish.

I installed Netbeans 10, JDK11 and Glassfish 5, but when I try to execute a basic "Hello World!", it returns an error saying "Glassfish server could not be started with JDK11. Please select another Java SE Platform".

Maybe, am I forgettig install something more?

Comment: The error message explains the problem precisely: you can't use JDK 11 with Glassfish 5 in NetBeans. Configure your Glassfish 5 server to use JDK 8 instead and everything will be fine. (You can add JDK 8 as a platform in NetBeans using **Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform**)

Answer (score 10):

*Only the glassfish server no longer supports the java 11 platform*

Therefore,the first you need to install java platform 8: 
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
Then you install it.

Back to Netbean, go to Tools>>Java Platforms>>JDK 1.8

***If you have JDK 1.8. you can run your project with JDK 1.8***

Answer (score 0):

1. Download  [jdk 8 with NetBeans 8.2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html)
2. Download glassfish: https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/download
3. goto `Tools`>>>`Servers`>>>`Add server`>> choose `glassfish`>> browse where u just download the glassfish and install.

Jdk 8 will work fine for all your projects

Answer (score 0):

You should change to use `Payara Server`.
It works like Glassfish (Maybe it's new version of Glassfish)