# Problem with Glassfish server on netbeans JDK not

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

So I'm a beginner at JEE and I only just installed Glassfish server, the problem is that it displays the error: **"GlassFish server could not be started with JDK 17(Default). Please select another Java SE Platform"**, I have found another similar issue, but I believe it was related to a JDK 11 wish is no longer supported however I have tested JDK 16 and 17 which are the latest versions.

Comment: [1] You haven't specified your versions of Glassfish and NetBeans. Update your question accordingly. [2] That said, you probably just need to add JDK 8 as a Java platform in NetBeans, and then use that when you configure Glassfish. [3] JDK 11 is still supported. [4] See the answers to [Does GlassFish server 5.1 can started with JDK15](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64191384/2985643) and [Start Glassfish in Netbeans 10 with JDK11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55447957/2985643) for clarification on what you need to do.

Comment: Sorry it's GlassFish5, and thanks for your answer I'll look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For today Glassfish 5 supports only Oracle JDK 8 Update 144 or later. With Payara 5 you can use JDK 11

Comment: But where can one find Oracle JDK 8 Update 144 or later? I've looked high and low without succuss.

Comment: Oops. Looks like I looked high but not low. Once at the Oracle page for JDK 8 updates I did a search for "144". It was indeed there, far down the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing jdk could not find problem, then install jdk 8 version for glashfish 4.1.1 . And set the environment path properly. After this your problem will be solved ✌️